# Changing visibility of VisualElement element doesn't cause Maui Windows app to redraw immediately

Tags: c#, maui, maui-windows

I am trying to set the visibility of a `Frame` after performing an async Task.

```
bool condition = await DoWorkAsync();

if (condition)
{
   Dispatcher.Dispatch(() =>
   {
       myFrame.IsVisible = true;
   });
}
```

When I run my app, the debugger tells me that my code is being called by the Dispatcher, but the app window does not show the Frame. (The frame remains hidden).

If I resize the app window, or otherwise cause it to "Invalidate", then my Frame will become visible.

Is there a way to force an Invalidate in a Maui Windows app?

If not, is there some other way I am supposed to set the visibility of a frame from my code behind?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/1416

Comment: Thanks for the link. The issue is Closed, so I'll add a comment that I am still seeing it in Preview 13.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a call to `InvalidateMeasure()` seems to have forced an update.

```
bool condition = await DoWorkAsync();

if (condition)
{
   Dispatcher.Dispatch(() =>
   {
       myFrame.IsVisible = true;
       this.InvalidateMeasure();
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem and came up with the worst workaround possible (but it is still workaround). I added `Loaded` event handler in my custom control:

```cs
private void CustomControl_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (sender as StylePicker).IsVisible = ((VM)BindingContext).IsCustomControlVisible;
}
```

It's ugly and doesn't work as intended, but this workaround allowed me to get past the problem asap and mark it with brilliant TODO comment. Hope somebody will show us what is wrong here.